# What kind of ViewController is this

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uipopovercontroller

I just wanted to know what kind of `ViewController` is this. Is it a `ViewController Presented Modally` or a `UIPopover`.

[image: iPad Language]

Comment: This is modal view controller. A pop over always has a kind of a kink towards the view that popped it open

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a **ViewController Presented Modally** or rather **UIModalPresentationFormSheet**

Answer (score 0):

This is what popViewController looks like :
[image]

Notice that it is referring to **Choose Color**

A Modal View Controller, as in your case, has a different behavior